# Can I put a Timer in Ajax updatePannel in a masterpage?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I made a very simple pannel updating wich will query a database and show a message on masterpage through a label.

Thus, I've put an updatePannel with a label and a timer within (obviously with a scriptManager) in my site's masterpage.

However, when I try to interact with the `timer1` object, I receive an error message: "`object not set to an instance of an object`". I not receive this message when placing the schema in a blank page (without masterpage).

I must to run the query in masterpage because the users need to receive information whatever they are in my site.

How can I correctly place the components to do this work? what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is your timer either inside of the update panel or set as a trigger?

Comment: Inside the update panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was where I was putting the panel, label and timer. I put in contentPlaceHolder, where the problem occours. Now I put the control in the `form` tag, then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it within a master page without a problem. Here is the relevant code:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updMessage" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
    <asp:Timer ID="tmrMessage" Interval="5000" ontick="tmrMessage_Tick" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

From master page code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["Message"] = 1;
    }
}

protected void tmrMessage_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int message = (int)Session["Message"];
    lblMessage.Text = message.ToString();
    Session["Message"] = ++message;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but doensn't working with me. I'm trying to discover about the correct placing of the objects on asp, any news I'm going to post...

Comment: Ok - just let me know if you have any questions.